# How to get a height of grey area under a last row of the datagridview?

Tags: datagridview

I need to get a height of grey area when a windows is resize.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears fairly straight forward.

1. Create an (accumulator) variable `totalDisplaySize` to keep track
   of the total height of the “displayed” rows plus the column height.
2. Start a loop at the “First Displayed Row Index” and end at the
   last row.
3. Add each displayed row height to the accumulator `totalDisplaySize.`
4. Return the grids height – (minus) `totalDisplaySize.`

Adding a check in the loop to see if the `totalDisplaySize` becomes greater than the grids height, may look something like…

```
private int GetUnusedHeight() {
  int totalDisplaySize = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;
  for (int i = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++) {
    totalDisplaySize += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height;
    if (totalDisplaySize >= dataGridView1.Height)
      return 0;
  }
  return dataGridView1.Height - totalDisplaySize;
}
```